# Which AWS managed iam policy should be used for allowing transit gateway full access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, policy, transit-gateway

Iam creating a role and trying to attach an was managed policy for transit gateway full access.
But I am not able to find any policy with transit gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such AWS managed policy. So you can create your own [customer managed policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#customer-managed-policies). For example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "FullTransitGatewayPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*TransitGateway*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Depending on exactly what you need, you can add more permissions or be more selective.

Comment: @SUBHASPATIL How did it go? Any progress with the issue?